# the task is to change the getEpisodeInfo() method of the PodcastEpisode class. More details-----

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Still new to Javascript.. still learning..

the task is to change the getEpisodeInfo() method of the PodcastEpisode class, so that it'll return the episode duration in a more commonly accepted format.

```
 function getEpisodeInfo(){
return `${this.artist}. "${this.title}" - ${this.guest} ${this.getFormattedDuration()}`;
}
  

class PodcastEpisode {
  constructor(title, artist, guest,duration){
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.guest = guest;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.getEpisodeInfo =getEpisodeInfo
    
  }

  like(){
      this.isLiked = this.isLiked;
  }
   getFormattedDuration() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(this.duration / 60); // the total number of minutes
    const seconds = this.duration % 60; // the remainder of the division by 60
    return `${minutes}:${seconds > 9 ?  seconds : "0" + seconds}`; 
}
 
}
```

Comment: OK ... and what specifically do you need our help with? What does "a more commonly accepted format" mean? What is the current output, and the desired output? And where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're just trying to move the `getEpisodeInfo` function into the Class.

But, you can't use the `function` keyword inside the class to define a method.

Here's the full code:

```
class PodcastEpisode {
    constructor(title, artist, guest, duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.guest = guest;
        this.duration = duration;

    }

    like() {
        this.isLiked = true;
    }
    getFormattedDuration() {
        const minutes = Math.floor(this.duration / 60); // the total number of minutes
        const seconds = this.duration % 60; // the remainder of the division by 60
        return `${minutes}:${seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds}`;
    }

    getEpisodeInfo() {
        return `${this.artist}. "${this.title}" - ${this.guest} ${this.getFormattedDuration()}`;
    }

}
```

Now you can create a PodcastEpisode Object and call podcast.getEpisodeInfo().

Let me know if that's not what you're trying to do.